# Javascript : Multi Level radio buttons , second level radio button null value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a multi level radio buttons. The logic hides/shows the second level radio buttons, then select/check the first element input that shows based on the selected first level radio buttons. But for some reason when I select a second level radio button and I select another button in the first level radio buttons when I go back to the previous selected radio button. There is an error that the value is null. I'm kind of confused because in html it is already selected, but in UI it wasn't.

The process where I noticed the bug: Select A2 -> Select B3 -> Select A3 -> Select A2

Here's my code:

```
(https://jsfiddle.net/jakedsi/0yhnujez/)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - you were even ASKED not to post jsfiddle without code here

Comment: That is so NON-DRY as it can be. Please read up on [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified.

It is not simple due to your HTML, but I simplified the labels too

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dc9xyhLj/

```js
const filterForm = document.querySelector('form.fltr');

filterForm.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('[type=radio]')) return;
  const parent = tgt.closest('div');
  parent.querySelectorAll('input')
    .forEach(rad => rad.closest('label').classList.toggle('checked', rad.checked));
  if (!parent.matches('.ggrp')) return; // not a ggrp
  document.querySelectorAll('.dgrp div').forEach(div => {
    div.hidden = !div.matches(`.${tgt.id}`);
    if (!div.hidden) div.querySelector('input').click();
  });
});
```

```css
.fltr label.checked {
  border-color: #44D62C;
  color: #44D62C;
}
```

```html
<form class="fltr">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Graphics</legend>
    <div style="display: flex;" class="ggrp">
      <label class="checked"><input id="A1" name="gfx" type="radio" value="A1" checked /> A1</label>
      <label><input id="A2" name="gfx" type="radio" value="A2" /> A2</label>
      <label><input id="A3" name="gfx" type="radio" value="A3" /> A3</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Display</legend>
    <div style="display: flex;" class="dgrp">
      <div class="A1"><label class="checked"><input id="B1" name="dsp" type="radio" value="B1" checked /> B1</label> </div>
      <div class="A1 A2"><label><input id="B2" name="dsp" type="radio" value="B2" /> B2</label> </div>
      <div class="A2"><label><input id="B3" name="dsp" type="radio" value="B3" /> B3</label> </div>
      <div class="A3"><label><input id="B4" name="dsp" type="radio" value="B4" /> B4</label></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```